# Where/how to reply to comments?

Tags: discussion, comments

Suppose I ask a question on Stack Exchange. Now someone comments on the question asking for some additional details or makes some points to which I need to reply.

Typically to respond to it, I add another comment to that post. However, the comments have a word limit, so if my response is exceeding that, what is the correct way to reply -

1. Split the response and post more that 1 comment
2. Edit the original question I posted
3. Add an answer to the question where I reply to the comment

Answer (score 6):

> Add an answer to the question where I reply to the comment

## No

> Split the response and post more that 1 comment

May be according to the situation. That is if the person had the problem before and asking you did you tried this, then reply in comment.

Note that if you have to add multiple comment to reply, it should be added to the question(in most cases)

> Edit the original question I posted

## Definitely

#### if the person asking for clarification because your question is not clear enough

Answer (score 6):

I'd edit these into the question.  *Typically* I maintain the POV of the question and acknowledge the commenter in comments.

"Hey, I've added the output of my frobulator" is enough to let the someone know you did that, and once the comment thread has run its course, flag it for cleanup.

Any relevant information should always be in a question. Answers should *answer* the question, and comments are *transient* and short on purpose.